# run a cron job only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron

Hi I have to restart Apache from rails controller I tried to do that with `%x{}` and `system` commands but it fails so I decided to do it with cron Is it possible to make cron task that will be executed only once ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The run once version of cron is called `at`.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_%28Unix%29 for an explanation, and note that specifying "now" as the time causes it to run immediately.

Comment: To manage your `at` jobs there are `atq` to show the registered jobs, `atrm` to remove jobs from your `at` queue and `at -c <jobid>` to show you what exactly will be executed in which environment.

Answer (score 0):

To schedule a cron job to run only once is a bit tricky but can be done by a self deleting script! Schedule your script in the cron for the next minute or for other preferable time,

```
* * * * * /path/to/self-deleting-script
```

The self deleting script will be like,

```
#!/bin/bash
# <your job here>
crontab -l | grep -v $0 | crontab - # to delete your script from the cron
#restart your cron service
rm -f $0 #delete the script now
```

It solves my problem in an openwrt router where I could not install `at` command.